# How to access pods without services in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I was wondering how pods are accessed when no service is defined for that specific pod. If it's through the environment variables, how does the cluster retrieve these?

Also, when services are defined, where on the master node is it stored?

Kind regards, 
Charles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you define a service for your app , you can access it outside the cluster using that service
- Services are of several types , including nodePort , where you can access that port on any cluster node and you will have access to the service regardless of the actual location of the pod
- you can access the endpoints or actual pod ports inside the cluster as well , but not outside
- all of the above uses the kubernetes service discovery
- There are two type of service dicovery though
- Internal Service discovery
- External Service Discovery.

[image]

Comment: I thought Kubernetes DNS was an optional feature? Are you saying that you need DNS if you are accessing services from outside the cluster?

Comment: DNS is optional for highly recommended way of doing it

Comment: ENV vars vs DNS discussion is in the context of when your pod want to access a service from other pod

Comment: The kubernetes service object uses labels and iptables rules

Comment: I understand. but how does one pod know the port and IP from another pod? Does it make a request to the master that it wants to reach a certain pod, who then answers with the right ENV vars to the calling pod?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot "access" a pods container port(s) without a service. Services are objects that define the desired state of an ultimate set of iptable rule(s).

Also, services, like all other objects, are stored in etcd and maintained through your master(s).

You could however manually create an iptable rule forwarding traffic to the local container port that docker has exposed.

Hope this helps! If you still have any questions drop them here.

Comment: Okay, I understand that services are necessary for access from outside the cluster and stored in the etcd in the master node. Imagine that pod 1 on node A, wants to access a functionality provided by pod 2 on node B. How does pod 1 know how to reach pod 2, if there are no services?

Answer (score 5):

Just for debugging purposes, you can forward a port from your machine to one in the pod:

```
kubectl port-forward POD_NAME HOST_PORT:POD_PORT
```

If you have to access it from anywhere, you should use services, but you got to have a deployment created

Create deployment

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/service/networking/run-my-nginx.yaml
```

Expose the deployment with a NodePort service

```
kubectl expose deployment deployment/my-nginx --type=NodePort --name=nginx-service
```

Then list the services and get the port of the service

```
kubectl get services | grep nginx-service
```

Answer (score 1):

- All cluster data is stored in etcd which is a distributed key-value store. If etcd goes down, cluster becomes unstable and no new pods can come up.
- Kubernetes has a way to access any pod within the cluster. Service is a logical way to access a set of pods bound by a selector. An individual pod can still be accessed irrespective of the service. Further service can be created to access the pods from outside the cluster (NodePort service)

Comment: Does the cluster store a backup of the etcd somewhere?

Comment: @CharlesVanDamme It is a distributed etcd store. Typically, all distributed systems store multiple copies in a cluster of machines