# K8s - DNS Resolution between pods in different namespaces

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dns, kubectl

I have a simple pod in a namespace called `"a"`, 
and another pod in a namespace `"b"`...

I also have a test script that makes a grpc call from `"a"` to `"b"`.

1. This script **does not work** in using the FQDN (e.g. "some-service.b.cluster.local")
2. This script **does work** if using the exact IP Address of the pod in "b" namespace

I suppose is some error in DNS Resolution, 
but I can't really move forward.

Any help?

```
kubectl exec -n a somepod-f647b7d95-mrvfr cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 10.12.0.10
search chimera.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local c.<company-name>-staging.internal <provider>.internal
options ndots:5
```

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system

event-exporter-v0.2.4-6d4c69fbfb-f4xpf                           1/1     Running   0          24d
fluentd-gcp-scaler-6965bb45c9-mzvw6                              1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-2m2bf                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-2v6bq                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-4xpbc                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-7g5hm                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-8mqvc                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-f9hrs                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-fr58c                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-hzrsb                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-kq8hc                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-kt6p5                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-nsztm                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-qcl4r                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-qggv9                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-qkkp5                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-rm9hn                                         1/1     Running   0          5d5h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-sv52h                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-t75fp                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-v49fv                                         1/1     Running   0          7d6h
kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-jnntn                                        4/4     Running   0          24d
kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-txmlj                                        4/4     Running   0          24d
kube-dns-autoscaler-8687c64fc-29jgq                              1/1     Running   0          7d6h
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-api-v2-201908101259587443-01f0b55b-q0k3   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-api-v2-201908101259587443-0d661dfb-3zhx   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-api-v2-201908101259587443-92bbd393-w96w   1/1     Running   1          115d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-es-single-202003021919386-1b520a2e-sn9m   1/1     Running   0          5d6h
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-es-single-202003021919386-bf6046bf-7wsp   1/1     Running   0          5d5h
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-es-single-202003021919386-d64daa4e-1jqz   1/1     Running   0          5d5h
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-general-20190810125958886-21ed2623-4m0p   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-general-20190810125958886-8b185cf9-x1j2   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-general-20190810125958886-eaf63d3c-k338   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-kafka-2019081012595876540-429586da-m2qf   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-kafka-2019081012595876540-76ebb654-z7xx   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-kafka-2019081012595876540-c3abee6e-4q76   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-rabbitmq-2019081012595876-552d6676-8z2k   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-rabbitmq-2019081012595876-662980f7-76jc   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-rabbitmq-2019081012595876-b269df22-6zqj   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-redis-2019081012595877180-38264a5e-c0ch   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-redis-2019081012595877180-9412d5f5-pt3w   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-proxy-gke-iceberg-redis-2019081012595877180-947dc20b-c002   1/1     Running   0          217d
kube-state-metrics-67b67d8fdd-nkpt4                              2/2     Running   0          24d
l7-default-backend-fd59995cd-cvqwb                               1/1     Running   0          24d
metrics-server-v0.3.1-5c8f664b95-sthjz
```

Comment: add content of /etc/resolv.conf from pod a and check if coredns pod are running in kube-system namespace

Comment: (updated) we use `kube-dns`

Comment: Have you tried some-service.b.svc.cluster.local?

Comment: yeah, I did... it;s not being resolved

Comment: add the output of kubectl get pods -n kube-system

Comment: done, just updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your description it appears you're running KubeDNS. My First piece of advice to you would be to [migrate](https://coredns.io/2018/05/21/migration-from-kube-dns-to-coredns/) to CoreDNS as KubeDNS is on a [deprecation path](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1943).

Secondly, two things leap out at me.

1. You're talking about making calls between pods instead of [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). While Kubernetes does provide Service Discovery between your applications, it does this through DNS as you know. However, just because pods can resolve each other [doesn't mean](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53517878/3066788) a container will have its ports exposed outside of its pod. To do this, even to an application within the cluster than can resolve it, you must declare a Service resource for each Pod or Controller.
2. When you talk about making a call that references a FQDN of your B pod/service, you do not specify the default FQDN schema and do not mention having customized this.

First, can you please `kubectl get svc -n NAMESPACE` for both namespaces in which your A and B pods are running and confirm that a Service of type [ClusterIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types) has been created and an IP Address has been associated with the Service?

Secondly, can you try and perform a connection attempt from Application A to the Service of Application B by [specifying the following FQDN format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55650127/3066788) instead?

`some-service.b.svc.cluster.local`

Notice the **svc** portion. You mentioned `some-service.b.cluster.local` in your OP.

Lastly, if everything comes back normal we can start troubleshooting `kube-dns`. it does appear that all three pods are running. However, have you tried to [describe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application-introspection/) them and/or [grab their logs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)? Could you try the following and share a summary if anything looks interesting?

```
kubectl describe pod -n kube-system kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-jnntn
kubectl describe pod -n kube-system kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-txmlj
kubectl describe pod -n kube-system kube-dns-autoscaler-8687c64fc-29jgq
```

```
kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-jnntn
kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-dns-6cd7bbdf65-txmlj
kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-dns-autoscaler-8687c64fc-29jgq
```

I imagine the `logs` commands will provide you with the answer you're looking for. Let me know if you need any further clarification or help on this issue. I'm happy to help.